# The top panel UI suddenly changed

Tags: home-page-component

I have a professional edition and my top panel (where the app menu is) changed its look and feel.
I don't know why but it happened a week ago.
See this image:

[image]

Why this happened and how can I go back to the regular look.

Comment: Did you check Setup > Customise > User Interface > Apply New skin (or similar)

Comment: The new theme is applied.

Comment: It happens only for one user out of six. All use chrome (not that I think it matters). Very strange. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It seems someone change the Accessibility mode on my account, which caused this issue.